Revert line by line in VS Code diff / compare files
VS Code has a very useful diff tool for comparing files (e.g. through the select file -> compare with selected dialogs).  I really like this tool and use it a lot, but often wish that I could "revert" line by line instead of by block.
When there are differences between the two files, VS Code will give you an arrow to convert the right file contents to match the left (revert block tooltip), but it's one block of changes at a time instead of line by line. Is there a way to do this line by line instead?
